# Speech recognition library in C++ for XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks, speech-recognition

I would like to add a Speech Recognition function to my C++ application programmed with XCode.
I did some Speech Recognition library hunting and here are the best candidates:

- OpenEars
- CMUSphinx
- Voce

Nevertheless, none of these solutions are satisfying, for several reasons (that might not be a 100% true statement).

My questions are:

1. Did you ever try to use a Speech Recognition library in a C++ program with XCode?
2. Do you have an advice about which library/framework to use?
3. If some work has already been done, might it be possible to have a basic sample code of it? (just for the beginning...)

Note: the speech recognition function I would like to create is very simple: 10 words (in english) that increment 10 variables each time they are said and recognized, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some searches I figured out that the apple **Carbon API** had a **SpeechRecognition.h** framework!

The bad news is that it seems **quite old** and that the **documentation/help on internet is quite poor**...

Anyone to have some experience about this framework?

Thanks for your help!